# How to run interface exe file by PHP?

Tags: php, exec, freeze

I use php to run an external exe file:

```
<?php
$command = '"F:\\An Software\\abc.exe"';
exec($command);
?>
```

`abc.exe` is an interface file, that no command line output.
I check Task Manager and see that abc.exe already running, but I can't see its window. And the browser can't not finish it request.
I think the problem is describle in this [php.net document](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) about exec function:

```
If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running
in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or
another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the
execution of the program ends.
```

But I don't know how to solve it. Can you tell me a solution? Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked `COM` object, as shown [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#43917)?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#86329) solution from the comments? It says: "This will execute $cmd in the background (no cmd window) without PHP waiting for it to finish, on both Windows and Unix. "

Comment: Your two solution make php working without wait exe file return, but it still dont allow exe file show inteface windows.